# Plex server is intercepting localhost (calls from JDownloader)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, localhost, plex, jdownloader

I've been using Plex Server for some times without issues on Linux Mint Cinnamon.

I've just installed JDownlader2, which works fine, except for the captcha parts that try to open the browser and I end up with a page from Plex Server everytime.

I've tried changing the port in Jdownloader's settings and to turn off `plexmediasever`'s service, but I can get to it to open the browser normally...
I always end up on `http://localhost:32400/manage`

Any pointers ?